# Resize Grid with GridSplitter

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, grid, gridsplitter

I have the following `Grid` where I want to introduce a `GridSplitter` to resize the content of the `Expander` if it's expanded:

```
<Grid Grid.Row="2" Margin="0,5,0,0" >
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Row="0">
        <!-- Menu -->
    </Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <!-- Main-Content -->
    </Grid>
    <GridSplitter Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="3"/>
    <Expander Grid.Row="3" Margin="0,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Header="Details">
        <TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding DetailsViewModels}">
            <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayHeader}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        </TabControl>
    </Expander>
</Grid>
```

My problem now is the size of the `Expander`-Content and the resize-behavior when I move the `GridSplitter`.

If I set the Height of the `RowDefinition` where the Expander is to *, then it takes way to much space if the expander is expanded.

If I set a MaxHeight at the `TabControl` then I can make the `TabControl` smaller if the `Expander` is expanded. But if the maxheight is reached only the `GridSplitter` continous moving.

If I don't set any size, the `TabControl` takes it full heigth, what unfortunately is too much.

How can I achieve that the `TabControl` takes a certain max amount of heigth but I can increase it using my `GridSplitter`?

Comment: Is it a way to bind the `MaxHeight` or `MaxWidth` of `TabControl` to the `Height` or `Width` of `Expander` with a some value converter,

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can catch the event Expanded of the Expander from code behind and set the desired size of the grid yourself ?

Comment: The problem is not the `Expander` at the moment of expanded. The problem is that I want to resize the content of the `Expander` by moving the `GridSplitter`